# Removing the character from String

Tags: java

I'm encrypting the text by using Vigenere cipher. Usually, I this method the key has to shorter than the original text, but what if the key is longer than the text? Can someone help me figure out ho to make the key equal to the text

NOTE: I already know how to encrypt the text.

The expected output should be: CIPHER_

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test {

public static void main (String [] a) {  
String bellasoStr = "CIPHER_IS_LONGER_THAN_THE_PLAIN_TEXT";//key
String plainText = "TESTING";//String


int x = plainText.length();
int y = bellasoStr.length();
String bellasoEncrypted = "";


char[] chars1 = bellasoStr.toCharArray();


if (!bellasoStr.equals(plainText)) {
    for (int i = 0; i < plainText.length(); i++) {
        bellasoStr = bellasoStr.substring(0, bellasoStr.length() - i);

    }
    System.out.println(bellasoStr);
}
```

Comment: Why would you need to? Just encrypt your text using as many lookups as necessary for the input string - you might cycle the cypher if it's short, but if it's longer than the input, you just ignore the rest? That said, you're in Java, String has a built in `substring()`, making your cypher as long as your input is basically trivial given that, looking at your code, you already know how to get the length of a string.

Comment: it's an assignment, so that's why I need to do it

Comment: then `String.substring` is where you want to be looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following statement in a controlled way

```
bellasoStr = bellasoStr.substring(0, bellasoStr.length() - i);
```

i.e.

```
if(bellasoStr.length() <= plainText.length()) {
    bellasoStr = bellasoStr.substring(0,  bellasoStr.length() - i);
}
```